# PHP gives error but still executes mysql procedure in later statements and inserts data in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page, which gives error because a radio value is not selected, but next statement is execution of procedure- procedure is still executed and i can see the values in the database. How to avoid this?

The error is

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: gender in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb\1_SubmitNewStudent_1.php on line 26

Comment: `PHP Notice` -> not an error, but a notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "default" value of the `radio` set by adding `checked` to one of the options like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="n/a" checked />N/A<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />Female<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" />Male<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go pass it just simply by checking if the value is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['gender']) {

//your code goes here 

}
```

In production you won't see it probably because of `error_reporting(0);` but it is a good practice to check those requests.

You can use `error_reporting("E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE");` this will provide you with the functionality of viewing all errors except notices which are not fatal. **You put it at the top of your page!**

Comment: Thanks - I can handle it as you mentioned or setting it NOT NULL in database. But I want to know how to stop PHP processing further after error .

Comment: error_reporting(0); - stops This is the code as I mentioned it. When you put something in production you always disable all errors or make them visible just for you so if something is broken you can present to the user some pretty page but you can see the error message. I will edit my post